# ANDROID : Stop restart app from next screen

Tags: android

The below flow is

MainActivity -> NextActivity(Press **Home** device button then click app icon from home screen of the device and again click Back button from this screen and app is getting restart) -> Restart**strong

Flow should be MainActivity -> NextAcivity(-------same desc-----) -> MainActivity

Please give me solution for this